# Rails 4 and fields_for using seed data. How to pre-populate form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for

The goal is to pre-populate the form with seed data: https://github.com/ornerymoose/GarageApp

The relevant code for iterating over stall numbers is in `garages_controller.rb`:

```
  def new
    @garage = Garage.new
    for i in 1..5 
      @garage.cars.build :stall_number => i
    end
  end
```

This will give 5 stall_number string values of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. **Instead of that**, how would I iterate over the values in the `seeds.rb` file?

```
Car.create(stall_number: "stall1")
Car.create(stall_number: "stall2")
Car.create(stall_number: "stall3")
Car.create(stall_number: "stall4")
Car.create(stall_number: "stall5")
```

So instead of the stall_numbers having values of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. They would have the string values listed in the seeds.rb file.

Here is the `fields_for` block in the garage `_form.html.erb`:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :cars do |builder| %>
      <p>Enter license for car parked in stall: <%= builder.object.stall_number %></p>
      <%= builder.label :license, "License #:" %><br />
      <%= builder.text_field :license %>
  <% end %>
```

Any input on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the same loop in the seed file.

```
for i in 1..5 
  Car.create(stall_number: "stall" + i.to_s)
end
```

If they are static, just create them in an array and call them.

```
array = ["stallA", "stallDC", "stall874", "stallNN", "stallPO", "stalSF", "stallRE", "stall456", "stall39", "stall99"]

array.each {|x| Car.create(stall_number: x)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What if the stall_number strings were more dynamic though? Ie, "Stall ABC", "Stall XYZ", so on so on.

Comment: Then you would need to add code that will append whatever string you are looking for. The 'i.to_s' is converting the integer to a string, so you just would append without conversion since it's already a string. "stall" + StringVariable. Where would these dynamic strings be generated? Are they static and off of a list, or does someone enter the string value?

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. But to call them in the controller, if I had 10 stall_numbers and wanted those form fields to be populated from the seed file: `10.times {@garage.cars.build(:name => Car.name)}` just returns `Car`. What's the proper way to go about this?

Comment: It seems that you need to add a stall model and associate it with the garage then associate the car to the stall. From your current schema, it appears that you might have multiple garages. If so, you will always only have 10 spots and they will always be named the same thing? This way, you can populate each garage's stalls. Is this correct, or do you want it static with 10?